# Grouping many points into closest pairs - Python + LP

Tags: python, geometry, gis, closest-points

I have a list which contains a shop_id, latitude, and longitude. Assuming we have an even amount of points, I would like to match each shop to another shop such that our connections are unique and we minimise the overall distance.

I was curious if my approach is not too stupid and what a better one would be. This currently works in a reasonable amount of time (an hour) for 1000 points.

Imagine we have a list like this:

```
shops = [[1, '53.382072', '-2.7262165'],
[2, '52.478499', '-0.9222608'],
[3, '52.071258', '-1.2722802'],
...]
```

And that I use PuLP to create an .lp file using this workflow:

```
prob = LpProblem("Minimise distance",LpMinimize)
# Variables
x = []
xnames = []
for one in store_connect(shops):
    xnames.append(one)
    x.append(LpVariable(one,0,1,LpInteger)) 
print("Created %d variables" % len(x))
# Objective
prob += pulp.lpSum([i[1]*x[i[0]] for i in enumerate(distances(shops))])
print("Created objective")
# Constraints
counter = 0
for constraint_rw in all_constraints(shops):
    prob += pulp.lpSum(x[xnames.index(one_cn)] for one_cn in constraint_rw) == 1
    counter += 1
    if counter % 10 == 0:
        print("Added %d contraints out of %d" % (counter,len(shops)))   
# Save "LP" file for other solvers
prob.writeLP("for_cplex.lp")
```

Where I call a few generator functions (to help the RAM ...)

```
def store_connect(shops):
    """
    Cross stores and return connection e.g. "v1-2" by ID
    """
    for i in range(len(shops)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(shops)):
            yield 'v'+str(shops[i][0])+'-'+str(shops[j][0])

def distances(shops):
    """
    Return distance in miles for crosses
    """
    for i in range(len(shops)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(shops)):
            yield haversine([shops[i][1],shops[i][2]],
                            [shops[j][1],shops[j][2]])

def all_constraints(shops):
    """
    Return constraint row
    """
    for a in shops:
        cons = []
        for b in shops:
            if a[0]<b[0]:
                cons.append("v"+str(a[0])+"-"+str(b[0]))
            elif a[0]>b[0]:
                cons.append("v"+str(b[0])+"-"+str(a[0]))
        yield cons
```

If I run this on 100 stores it's very quick and I can use the default PuLP solver. Otherwise I submit the LP file to CPLEX on NEOS servers. I created a small helper function which visualises the resulting matches:

Here is how my LP file looks for a trivial example of 10 stores (truncated):

```
Minimize
OBJ: 131.513 v1_10 + 97.686 v1_2 + 109.107 v1_3 + 36.603 v1_4 + 11.586 v1_5
 + 109.067 v1_6 + 113.862 v1_7 + 169.371 v1_8 + 220.098 v1_9 + 101.958 v2_10
 + 31.793 v2_3 + 61.792 v2_4 + 105.822 v2_5 + 73.055 v2_6 + 32.008 v2_7
 + 81.627 v2_8 + 122.493 v2_9 + 72.945 v3_10 + 72.983 v3_4 + 114.609 v3_5
 + 46.098 v3_6 + 5.555 v3_7 + 60.305 v3_8 ...
Subject To
_C1: v1_10 + v1_2 + v1_3 + v1_4 + v1_5 + v1_6 + v1_7 + v1_8 + v1_9 = 1
_C10: v1_10 + v2_10 + v3_10 + v4_10 + v5_10 + v6_10 + v7_10 + v8_10 + v9_10
 = 1
_C2: v1_2 + v2_10 + v2_3 + v2_4 + v2_5 + v2_6 + v2_7 + v2_8 + v2_9 = 1
_C3: v1_3 + v2_3 + v3_10 + v3_4 + v3_5 + v3_6 + v3_7 + v3_8 + v3_9 = 1
_C4: v1_4 + v2_4 + v3_4 + v4_10 + v4_5 + v4_6 + v4_7 + v4_8 + v4_9 = 1
_C5: v1_5 + v2_5 + v3_5 + v4_5 + v5_10 + v5_6 + v5_7 + v5_8 + v5_9 = 1
...
Binaries
v1_10
v...
End
```

The result:

[image: Matching 10 points]

```
Status: Optimal
Total minimised distance (miles):  190.575
```

Finally, here is a larger example on 1000 points:

[image]

Comment: This problem (`all pairs of closest points`) is effectively solved with kd-tree for euclidean distances. This approach doesn't work good for geocoordinates, but I am sure that similar data structures do exist for Lat/Lon in GIS systems and libraries. Another method - find minimal edge-weight matching in graph.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) solution (Python's data analysis package). My elementary geometry reminds me that between two points the closest distance is a straight line which in a coordinate plane is the hypotenuse between Lat and Lng points.

Below is first runs a cartesian product between shops (all possible combination between the sets) and then calculates the hypotenuse using geographic coordinates. From there, the minimium is aggregated:

```
import pandas as pd

# ORIGINAL LIST
shops = [[1, 53.382072, -2.7262165],
         [2, 52.478499, -0.9222608],
         [3, 52.071258, -1.2722802]]

# CONVERTING INTO TWO DUPLICATE SHOPS DATA FRAMES    
shopsdfA = pd.DataFrame(shops, columns=['ID_A', 'Lat_A', 'Lng_A'])
shopsdfA['key']=1
shopsdfB = pd.DataFrame(shops, columns=['ID_B', 'Lat_B', 'Lng_B'])
shopsdfB['key']=1

# CROSS JOINING BOTH DATA FRAMES FOR CARTESIAN PRODUCT SET 
compareshops = pd.merge(shopsdfA, shopsdfB, on='key')[['ID_A', 'Lat_A', 'Lng_A', 
                                                       'ID_B','Lat_B', 'Lng_B']]
#  (REMOVING SHOPS COMPARED TO ITSELF)
compareshops = compareshops[compareshops['ID_A'] != compareshops['ID_B']].\
               reset_index(drop=True)
#   ID_A      Lat_A     Lng_A  ID_B      Lat_B     Lng_B
#0     1  53.382072 -2.726217     2  52.478499 -0.922261
#1     1  53.382072 -2.726217     3  52.071258 -1.272280
#2     2  52.478499 -0.922261     1  53.382072 -2.726217
#3     2  52.478499 -0.922261     3  52.071258 -1.272280
#4     3  52.071258 -1.272280     1  53.382072 -2.726217
#5     3  52.071258 -1.272280     2  52.478499 -0.922261

# CALCULATE HYPOTENUSE
compareshops['hypotenuse'] = ((compareshops['Lat_A'] - compareshops['Lat_B']) ** 2 +
                              (compareshops['Lng_A'] - compareshops['Lng_B']) ** 2) ** (1/2)
#   ID_A      Lat_A     Lng_A  ID_B      Lat_B     Lng_B  hypotenuse
#0     1  53.382072 -2.726217     2  52.478499 -0.922261    2.017598
#1     1  53.382072 -2.726217     3  52.071258 -1.272280    1.957591
#2     2  52.478499 -0.922261     1  53.382072 -2.726217    2.017598
#3     2  52.478499 -0.922261     3  52.071258 -1.272280    0.536991
#4     3  52.071258 -1.272280     1  53.382072 -2.726217    1.957591
#5     3  52.071258 -1.272280     2  52.478499 -0.922261    0.536991

# AGGREGATE FOR MINIMUM HYPOTENUSE AND MERGE CORRESPONDING PAIRED IDS
compareshops = pd.merge(compareshops[['ID_A','hypotenuse']].groupby(['ID_A']).min().reset_index(),
                        compareshops[['ID_B','hypotenuse']], on='hypotenuse')
# (REMOVING SAME STORE PAIRINGS)
compareshops = compareshops[compareshops['ID_A'] != compareshops['ID_B']].\
                     reset_index(drop=True)[['ID_A','ID_B','hypotenuse']]

#   ID_A  ID_B  hypotenuse
#0     1     3    1.957591
#1     2     3    0.536991
#2     3     2    0.536991
```

One foreseeable challenge is your map does not have overlapping connections, only one pairing to each store. Possibly an iterative hypotenuse calculation will need to be run to find the "next" shortest distance.

Comment: Thanks Parfait; however is the Pandas solution really quicker/more accurate than setting up a linear optimisation?

Comment: All up to you! I am pretty sure you can set up a linear programming model in pandas a true dataset framework. Above was just another approach to skin the cat. I was particularly interested in the Cartesian set comparison of shops and applying the Euclidean distance formula!